# Why do some elements seem to disappear after scrolling due to position:fixed?

Tags: css

I'm having an odd issue with some css i've written. Basically i have a fixed sidebar with an `<hr/>` element on it, and displays properly when the page loads - HOWEVER when you scroll the sidebar down the `<hr/>` element disappears until you refresh it.

I've removed everything on the page one by one (all javascript, css, etc) and the only piece of code that seems to have an impact is `position: fixed` - if i remove this from the sidebar code the `<hr/>` element seems to work perfectly fine.

you can see this [on this page](https://silversunset.net/dbm/tutorials) if he helps. I've tried adding a width to the element and it doesnt seem to stop the weird vanishing behavior. Any help would be appreciated.

edit: this also applies if i put an empty `<div></div>` element with the same styling instead of an `<hr/>` element.

If its helpful this is the sidebar styling:

```
    .menubar {
        background-color: #343a40;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        z-index: 500;
        max-width: 250px!important;
        min-width: 250px!important;
        margin-left: -15px;
        padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    }
```

and this is the `<hr/>` styling

```
    .menubar hr {
        margin-top: 10px!important;
        margin-bottom: 10px!important;
        border: 0!important;
        width: 100%!important;
        height: 1px!important;
        z-index: 50!important;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(248, 249, 250, 0), rgba(248, 249, 250, 0.75), rgba(248, 249, 250, 0))!important;
    }
```

Comment: The <hr>s looks fine to me in Chrome and Firefox. In which browsers are you noticing the issue?

Comment: In the link you have mentioned, the `<hr>` works fine even after scrolling. (I've tested it in Chrome.)
I guess it would be browser compatibility issue. Can you tell me which browser are you using?

Comment: I've checked it on Chrome on two computers, Edge on one, and had a few friends with Firefox test it and they see the same thing. 
this is a gif of what i see https://i.imgur.com/8ym4YIO.gifv

Comment: Ah ok, I was able to see this happening in Windows 8. I would suggest trying to apply the dividers directly on the <ul> using pseudo elements. This is hard to debug without a jsfiddle/jsbin/codepen because editing the styles causes the browser to repaint, fixing the issue.

Comment: The gif uses `border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;` and `border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;` on the `<ul>` elements and has the same issue. I've tried moving it around to all sorts of places and get the same effect each time, i'm literally at a loss for why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken a look at this and you need to add position relative the the hr element, I am still working out a better way for you to lay up the code and I 100% recommend you taking a close look and refactoring the structure of your markup.

Comment: It's not clear why you suggest doing so. Please add some explanation.

Comment: I dont understand why you think i need to refactor anything, but adding the `position: relative` fixed my issue, thanks!

Comment: Just to add to this now I have a bit more time to explain the reasoning behind why you needed to apply a 'position: relative' to the '<hr />' element.

When you set an element to 'position: fixed;' you are positioning it relative to the viewport, because when you scroll, the '<hr />' is re-positioned due to being out of the viewport so setting it to 'position: relative' allows it to stay in position based on it being contained within the parent element that is being set to a fixed position.

I hope above makes sense as my original post hit character limit, so I had to reduce explanation.

Comment: @Silversunset to give reason why I feel you need to refactor the code is firstly, I have never experienced so many !important being set to override a style. Doing this will cause problems down the line and is honestly just really messy. Another thing I noticed is the use of classes. You have for example a class applied to a div that is simply for setting the text-align property to left, you are able to do this plenty of other ways. You also have the last <hr /> out of the header which doesn't make any sense. I am not on stackoverflow much so apologies for the honesty.

Comment: @tuj That’s because the page uses bootstrap, and bootstrap uses classes to apply styling.